# Eeeek! Who took away the green consecutive days in the calendar?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, calendar

Something has changed and now the visited days, in the calendar, are not marked with green anymore. Previously it was very easy to spot the missing days.

> [image: Empty]

It used to show as green for days I've visited, but that has disappeared. Same emptiness is in next month view as well:

> [image: NextMonth]

Found old picture with example of the old design in work:

> [image]

.

Comment: Is this the same issue as [Visited days calendar is disabled/bug on Profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375986/4642212)?

Comment: @Xufox, yes it seems to be similar. Sorry, I searched before posting but somehow I missed that one :(

Comment: Cross site meta dupes are fine. Please leave it here, i.e. don't delete. (And in future even if you see bug reported on per-site meta, also report in MSE if relevant to more/all sites.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks, will do.

Comment: Seems fixed now, my calendar is still bright green.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed, related to a lot of back-end furniture moving. Kermit isn't just an old file transfer protocol, it's also the name of a frog, that appreciated all things green.

The calendar now pays subtle, tacit attribute to both things, or even your favorite bright green thing, again.

Answer (score 0):

The calendar is not blank. The boxes with outlines are the days you visited; the boxes without outlines are the days you haven't visited. Here is a screnshot of my calendar, where you can see the contrast:

[image: Calendar]

October 1st does not have the outline because I did not visit on October 1st. The rest of the days do have the outline because I did visit on all those other days.

I don't think this is a bug. It may just be a change in how visits/non-visits are represented.

Comment: Definitely a bug. It used to show in bright green. Now it's not possible to tell unless you look really carefully.

Comment: It is a change indeed and I praise you for spotting that it is still working. We have seen lots of changes lately across the network. Not all of those were received well, let's see how this one goes down ;)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Well the functionality certainly hasn't been disabled, as alleged in the linked post. The color might be a bug.

Comment: Agree it's not a bug but it's super ugly by all means, and almost unnoticeable.

Comment: I can't tell which day I have not visited a site even if I look really carefully - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1yYb.png - Note that it says **12 consecutive** so one or more of the days should look different. Using Google Chrome Version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: @Pang. Interesting. It works for me.

Comment: @Alex It worked for you because the 1st day of the month is not surrounded by other days and it has no margins/borders. But for Pang, since 19th is surrounded by other boxes, is not noticeable anymore. So It's definitely a usage issue.

Comment: @Alex That is because you have at least two consecutive days that you didn't visit. Pang, was mentioning that he missed only one day. It's not easy to detect his missing day, see his link.

Comment: @dan That's a different bug, then. It's not that the system no longer marks visited days; it's that if a non-visited day is surrounded by visited days on all sides it will have the outline fromm the visited days.